# connecting physical NIC to hyper-v switch?

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

I'm trying to connect a physical NIC to a hyper-v switch which is NATed.
 Reason for a NAT switch is so my VMs can communicate with each other as well as the internet.

my interfaces are as follows:
WiFi adapter which is connected to the internet.
VEthernet which is my virtual switch.
NIC1 is connected to my NAS.
NIC2 not using, but would like to connect it to the virtual switch so that I can have physical machines get IP addresses from my Virtual domain controller with DHCP role installed  that is connected to the virtual switch.
I've tried:
bridging VEthernet switch with NIC2 but not sure what to do thereafter.
I have no clue how to go about acomplishing what I want to do.

Your help or any advice would be much appreciated.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the NIC to a VM in the settings of the virtual switch:

[screenshot of settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMAzE.jpg)

If you require a different NIC for each VM, then just create an individual switch for each VM.

Comment: Hi,I have tried your suggestion but no luck.
to clarify I did the following:
in the virtual switch manager created a new switch and chose external
I chose to connect it to NIC2.
I then highlighted the vm which is my virtual domain controller> settings, added a second VNic and connected it to the VSwitch I created earlier.
When I connect a machine to the second NIC, it assigns a private IP address.

I'm not sure what else I should do or perhaps I left out something?
Thanks for your reply thus far.
Regards